# Cannot recover key

Tags: java, android, eclipse, key

I published the first version of my app in Play Store two days ago. I used a key with a known alias and password.

Then, I changed the name of my app in eclipse, just changed one letter. Now, I want to export version 2 in eclipse, try use the key from the first time and enter alias and passwort. I´m sure they are correct!!

On the last step, Eclipse tells me "Cannot recover key". I tried it with a new one but then the Play Store shows an error. What can I do??

**EDIT:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Like you see in the second image abobe, it MUST be the right password because otherwise the alias would not be in the dropdownbox. Also the second password is correct, it´s a copy from the first. I only have one alias!

Destination APK file-link in the last picture doesn´t matter right?

Comment: 'Change name of app' Do you mean from the manifest? or Eclipse>project>refactor>rename?

Comment: In Eclipse, I clicked "refactor" - "rename"!

Comment: The error also occurs if you have not set the password for alias entry. I set the password to Alias also and it worked.

Answer (score 133):

**Solution: The KeyStore password and The Key password should be the same.**

Changing both passwords using keytool

**Change KeyStore password**

```
keytool -storepasswd -new %newpassword% -keystore %YourKeyStore%.jks
```

*replace %newpassword% with your actual password, same with YourKeyStore*

**Change Alias key Password**

```
keytool -keypasswd -alias %MyKeyAlias% -new %newpassword% -keystore KeyStore.jks
```

Note: supply old passwords for both keystore and alias when asked for them

(quoted from http://karim-ouda.blogspot.com/2010/07/errors-solutions-5.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot!
But WHY would they make it that way?

Comment: I have the same problem. I remember while I was exporting the signed application Eclipse froze. But the generated certificate seems okay. Now Im trying to upload an update but there is a problem with the update. I've tried to change it and I get the same error as you. Any suggestions?

Comment: The had stopped being the case in recent builds of Studio, seems to be back again in Android Studio 1.4, but using the same password fixes it.

Comment: Using the second command I get this error: `java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Cannot recover key`

Comment: I have encountered the same problem but I solved it differently. My problem was that I did not specify both the keystore and key password but the former only, and the implementation tries to open the key with the keystore password - this fails if the two are different.

Comment: This is really strange (and stupid). I have never had problems with this for years of using one keystore for a few of my apps. Now after upgrading to a new notebook, it suddently doesn't work anymore (why? on the previous notebook I've went through Eclipse and many different versions of Android Studio).

Comment: Fortunately, I was able to change the keystore password as described here but it means that I now have to have multiple copies of the keystore, each with a different password, matching the key I want to use! So why is it even possible to have multiple keys in one keystore (with different passwords)?

Comment: Its giving this error still now in my case: `keytool error: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Cannot recover key`

Comment: Interesting how it's explicitly mentioned in [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#generate-key) that these two passwords should be different

Comment: Using the same password is also required by SoapUI

Answer (score 13):

If you have special characters in you passwords use this tool to change it:

http://keystore-explorer.org/

I've tried the [commands](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17757850/5436000) on Windows and it didn't work(probably because of the special characters).

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Changing App Name doesn't create any problem while you signing the application. you might have entered a wrong password or keystore-alias.

And you cannot create a new keystore to sign the application. If you done so then it is another application and you cannot updated the currently existing application.

Try re-sign the app with First Keystore with proper keystore-alias and password. It may be hard for you but if you fail to re-sign with the first keystore file then you cannot update the app with second version.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I you think that that doesn´t create any problem, is there any way to show the password I used? Probably not..

Answer (score 0):

In my case the error was due a special character in the password: `Ç`.