# Android Studio : Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'. > Failed to read key from store: Cannot recover key

Tags: android, android-studio, parse-platform

This is my first time building my apk since the Android Studio (Beta) 0.8.1 release...so Im not sure if its related to this.  I think that performing the updated could have modified by AS settings, but Im not sure.  Can anyone possibly tell me why Im getting this error.  Here is a copy of my build.gradle file.  Please let me know if you need anything else.

This is happening when i try to generate an apk for all of my apps since ive updated to the 0.8.1 Beta Release.  Has anyone else had this problem.

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 4
        versionName "4.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree('src/main/libs')
    compile files('src/main/libs/Parse-1.5.1.jar')
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.3.23'
}
```

Comment: Sound like issue with signing. Can you check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14606837/cannot-recover-key

Comment: This answered my problem.  Thank You

http://stackoverflow.com/a/17757850/324444

Answer (score 3):

Your problem may be your Key store password and Key password do not match. The easiest and most simple way to fix this is by creating a new Key store path and setting the password to the same as your Key password.

Answer (score -1):

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFile getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        flavor1 {
        }
        flavor2 {
            proguardFile 'some-other-rules.txt'
        }
    }
```

Comment: its help me, I create,  apk build