# keytool error: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Cannot recover key android

Tags: android, android-keystore, signed-apk

I can't signed my apk with the existing keystore. Its giving me  this error when signing:
`com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key  Cannot recover key`

So, by following this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14606837/cannot-recover-key), I have tried to change the password but its giving me `keytool error: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Cannot recover key` error when executing this command:

`keytool -keypasswd -alias %MyKeyAlias% -new %newpassword% -keystore KeyStore.jks`

I have already a version available in playstore using this keystore.

Comment: If you forgot your password try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/34939599/5188051

this worked for me a while back....

Comment: I have my password. Problem is that suddenly this keystore is not working.

Comment: Try with that .jar file and with your password given as suggestions.... I used that to recover my password once when i had similar issue

Comment: I already said, I have my password.

Comment: Simply add you current key-store password without %, in order to change password and make sure that KeyStore password and The Keypassword should be same.

Comment: Remove % from command and try again, if your alias/password is correct it shouldbe working

Comment: @PravinD Tried but didn't work

Comment: I didn't use % anywhere

Comment: have you solved this

Answer (score 3):

I finally solved it by reading the document:
https://www.rickyadams.com/wp/index.php/2017/11/15/keytool-java-keystore-ssl/

As I use a different storepass and keypass.

Verify the private key password by attempting to change it

```sh
> keytool -keypasswd -keystore KEYSTORE -alias ALIAS -storepass PASSWORD
```

This is the output you’ll see if a key password isn’t set, or if the key password is the same as the store password:

```sh
New key password for <ALIAS>:
```

This is the output you’ll see if a key password is set and you enter it incorrectly:

```sh
Enter key password for ALIAS:
keytool error: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Cannot recover key
```

This is the output you’ll see if a key password is set and you enter it correctly:

```sh
Enter key password for <ALIAS>:
New key password for <ALIAS>:
```

Comment: Working link to said blog post is now https://www.rickyadams.com/wp/keytool-java-keystore-ssl/

Answer (score 0):

**Looks like missing private key.**