# Android Cannot recover key

Tags: android, android-studio, keystore, android-keystore

I'm having an error recovering my key in Android Studio.

I know the key alias and I have the correct password for both.

I know this because I am able to run: `keytool -list -v -keystore mykeystore.jks -alias myKey -storepass myPass -keypass myPass`
in cmd and get my certs.

My storepass and keypass are the same and I copied and pasted all of the values from cmd to android studio, but I still get this error.
I've also tried restarting android studio and manually retyping my passwords and alias multiple times to no avail.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14606837/cannot-recover-key Or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29997688/android-studio-cannot-recover-key

Comment: Yep, checked those guys and changed my key and store password (which was different) to the same password before posting, but it doesn't seem to have fixed the issue...

Comment: Did you ever solve this? Having exactly this issue.