# Cannot recover key - When generating Signed APK

Tags: android, keystore, jks

I'm trying to release a signed version of my APK but I keep getting an "cannot recover key" error.

I've found lots of questions based around the same problem but none of the solutions are working for me and I honestly don't know what else to do.

I wrote the keystore and key alias passwords down so I'm pretty sure they are correct, these errors have given me some doubt.

I've tried the answer listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29997688/android-studio-cannot-recover-key). This gives me:

> java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException : Cannot Recover Key.

I've tried following this video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nS3wxnLgZOo). I found both my passwords and yet still the same problem.

I've tried this answer too [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42979566/7911961), again I got the same UnrecoverableKeyException as the first attempt.

I've also done [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44690499/7911961). And like this user I can see my certificates, I'm not sure if that helps.

I was advised to check the lint report and got a "Congratulations - No issues found" message.

PS. Just to be clear would creating a new key (not key store) for the app result in the Playstore seeing it as a new application ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never managed to fix this error by finding the key.

When I did upload the app to the developer console I seem to have signed the app up for google's app signing.

Flowing the documentation listed [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423?hl=en). I created a new Keystore(to avoid confusion with the previous key if i used the old keystore), created a new key and generated an upload certificate as instructed by the documentation.

I then sent google a ticket, saying I lost my key and attached the upload certificate to the ticket. Two days later I was contacted by a member of the support staff who has said the new certificate was successfully uploaded and after another two days it'll be in affect.

So after waiting the two days I managed to push an update to my app with no problems.

I know this isn't a fix for finding the previous key, but I do hope it'll help someone else who runs into a similar issue.